# on delay and off delay in one circuit

Tags: timer

How to build a 555-circuit IC with a delay at the beginning and a delay at the end?

I want to make a LDR switch that When it gets dark Turn on the relay after 10 sec and When there is light Turn off the relay after 10 sec.Please help me build this circuit

Comment: Maybe this circuit can be made with transistor. Is there anyone to help?

Comment: is this for turning on a lamp at night?

Comment: yes. turn on lamp at night and turn off at day. But these delays are needed to prevent possible noise, such as a bird sitting on the sensor for a short time, or cloudy weather for a short time.

Comment: Why not use a simple CMOS schmitt gate. The input is a resistor, from the signal source to the input of the gate with a capacitor from the input of the gate to ground. A CD40106 is a hex inverter, use 1 as the input and feed the remaining five connected in parallel as the output. This will be good for a 12V system. This automatically filters noise out of the input.

Comment: I want the circuit to be simple and cheap. By that I mean the noise did not activate the relay immediately after dark and also did not turn off the relay immediately after it turned on. If this is not a delay, if the circuit is exposed to the light of the lamp, it will start turning off and on again and again.